# Repace blank line (LF only) in Notepad++ with text

Tags: notepad++

I have tried at least half a dozen suggestions for this issue but none of them are working for me.

My exact situation:

I started with a file containing text on every line (252 total lines).
I need to insert a 'y' between each line so the file should look like:

```
text
y
text
y
text
y
```

etc.

Step 1)  I used the following regex to insert a blank line between lines:
Find: \n
Replace: \n\n

This worked fine.  At this point I have:

```
text

text

text
```

etc.

*NOTE*  When I go into View\Show Symbol\Show End of Line, there are CRLF at the end of every line
containing text, but only LF for the new blank lines.

At this point I want to replace the blank lines (LF only) with the letter 'y'.

*NOTE 2*  The 'text' lines are commands for a piece of networking equipment.  This particular command
then comes back with the verbose equivalent of 'Are you sure?'.  I want to feed it a 'y'.

I have tried numerous suggestions from several different posts but nothing I do will replace the LF lines with a 'y' AND leave the other lines alone.

I have tried things like: ^\n$ to isolate the blank lines but even this does not work.

Several other suggestions from this and other sites are also not giving me the result I require.

Comment: I think you can search for `$` and replace with `\ny`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do it in 1 step, searching for the end of the line and replace with a newline followed by `y`

If you want to skip completely empty lines, you can assert a char to the left

```
(?<=.)$
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Press ctrl + H in notepad++ file where you want to replace blank line with y.
2. Select the Extended mode.
3. Search for \n\r and add y in replace with, then click on replace All.
   Please reference this link https://www.screencast.com/t/92d1J4QW